# Best Data Structure for Priority Queue implementation

Tags: data-structures

Which is the best Data Structure for Priority Queue implementation and why ?

name some other Data Structures other than the best one to implement a Priority Queue and Tell its advantages and Disadvantages .Thanks. Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks in advance so much thnx

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Implementation

Comment: You can't delete on mobile. Go to the site.

Comment: What NExt ?? What NExt ?? What NExt ??

Comment: Give a few more details !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a heap is used because of the quick inserts O(log N)

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

For a discussion of the various structures used, and their advantages and disadvantages, see the discussion available here:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: any other reason please? as in linked-list there is insertion time is O(1)

Comment: While inserting may take constant time, peeking and initial building (search) can be expensive. Every data structure is a trade off, and most can be used for most situations. It's all about trade-off and efficiencies.